# Populating an ObjectList from a database

Tags: vb.net

I have manually populated time slots: BookedTimeSlots As New List(Of String) From {"08h00-09h00", "10h00-11h00", "12h00-13h00", "16h00-17h00", "18h00-19h00"}. I am trying to populate the BookedTimeSlots Object from my database with the method. DTCurrentBookingsTableAdapter.FillObject(DsEventBooking13.DTCurrentBookings, MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString). I am getting "0 " being returned instead of the time slots in the SQL query. My query returns the desired time slots.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting zero instead of anything else. That's exactly what you should be getting.

Table adapters have, by default, two methods for querying the database: `Fill` and `GetData`. The former takes an existing typed `DataTable` as an argument and populates it with the result set of the query, returning the number of records retrieved. The latter creates a new typed `DataTable` internally, populates it and returns it.

You can add extra queries to your table adapter and it will add a pair of methods, one that acts like `Fill` and one that acts like `GetData`. They are usually named `FillBySomeColumn` and `GetDataBySomeColumn`, where `SomeColumn` is the column you use to filter the results of the query.

Given that your method `FillObject` has a name starting with *"Fill"* and is accepting an existing typed `DataTable`, the data retrieved will be in that `DataTable` after the call and the number returned is the number of records retrieved. If the value returned is zero then that means that you have no data in the database that matches the filter in your query.

Basically, everything is working exactly as it should. The problem is that either your database doesn't contain the data that you think it should or you're passing it the wrong filter value.